# Send-MailMessage, state never when LastLogonDate = never?

Tags: powershell, email, null

Using the ps below I'm emailing specific personnel certain AD account properties including LastLogonDate. If the account was never used the email omits the value entirely. I'd like the message to include something like the following:
John Smith logged onto our systems a total of 0 times with the last successful log in posted on N/A.
How can I modify what I have to accomplish this? Thanks!

```
# List every active account with a "SACRequest Account" desctription that will expire in 0,7,14 days and inlcude the name and email address of the original account requester (extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2)
import-module activedirectory
$Today = Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyy'
$Rightnow = Get-Date -Format o
$reportObject = @()
$userList = get-aduser -filter {Description -like "SACRequest Account" -and Enabled -eq $True} -Properties displayname, accountExpires, description, passwordexpired,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",enabled,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate,logoncount,passwordlastset, badlogoncount,lastbadpasswordattempt,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2,department | 
select displayname, accountExpires, description, passwordexpired,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",enabled,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate,logoncount,passwordlastset, badlogoncount,lastbadpasswordattempt,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2,department |
sort-object msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed -descending
$obj = new-object PSobject
foreach ($user in $userList) 
{
$obj = new-object PSobject
    $obj | add-member noteproperty Name($user.displayname)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty Description($user.description)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'Password Expired'($user.Passwordexpired)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'Account is Enabled'($user.Enabled)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'AccountExpirationDate'($user.AccountExpirationDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'LastLogonDate'($user.LastLogonDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'Password Last Set'($user.PasswordLastSet)   
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'Failed Logon Attempt'($user.lastbadpasswordattempt) 
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'TotalLogonCount'($user.logoncount)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'Total Failed Logons'($user.badlogoncount)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'SACSubmitter'($user.extensionAttribute1)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'SACSubmitterEmail'($user.extensionAttribute2)
    $obj | add-member noteproperty 'Department'($user.department)
    $reportObject += $obj}

$from    =  "System Access Control <systems@organization.org>"

foreach ($user in $reportObject) {
  if (([datetime]$user.AccountExpirationDate).AddDays(-0) -eq $TodayOnly) 
  {
    $Name = $user.name
    $to = $user.SACSubmitterEmail
    $subject =  "Your contractors's login account will expire today!"
    $hello = $user.SACSubmitter
    $AccountExpirationDate = $user.AccountExpirationDate # -as [datetime]
    $TotalLogonCount = $user.TotalLogonCount
    $LastLogonDate = $user.LastLogonDate
    $body =  "Hello $hello,<br><br>"
    $body +=  "The login account you requested for <b>$Name</b> will expire in one week on <b> $AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "$name logged onto our systems a total of <b>$TotalLogonCount</b> times with the last successful log in posted on <b> $LastLogonDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "<a href='http://intranet/form.cfm?id=100'>If this account needs to remain active please submit a new System Access Control Request by clicking here.</a><br><br>"
    $body +=  "Kind Regards,<br>"
    $body +=  "Your friends in IT<br><br><br>"
    $body +=  "<i>Data generated $RightNow</i>"
    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $mail.IsBodyHTML=$true
    $server = "mail.organization.org"
    $port   = 25
    $Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server,$port
    $Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $smtp.send($mail)
}
}

foreach ($user in $reportObject) {
  if (([datetime]$user.AccountExpirationDate).AddDays(-7) -eq $TodayOnly) 
  {
    $Name = $user.name
    $to = $user.SACSubmitterEmail
    $subject =  "Your contractors's login account will expire in one week!"      
    $hello = $user.SACSubmitter
    $AccountExpirationDate = $user.AccountExpirationDate # -as [datetime]
    $TotalLogonCount = $user.TotalLogonCount
    $LastLogonDate = $user.LastLogonDate
    $body =  "Hello $hello,<br><br>"
    $body +=  "The login account you requested for <b>$Name</b> will expire in one week on <b> $AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "$name logged onto our systems a total of <b>$TotalLogonCount</b> times with the last successful log in posted on <b> $LastLogonDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "<a href='http://intranet/form.cfm?id=100'>If this account needs to remain active please submit a new System Access Control Request by clicking here.</a><br><br>"
    $body +=  "Kind Regards,<br>"
    $body +=  "Your friends in IT<br><br><br>"
    $body +=  "<i>Data generated $RightNow</i>"
    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $mail.IsBodyHTML=$true
    $server = "mail.organization.org"
    $port   = 25
    $Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server,$port
    $Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $smtp.send($mail)
}
}

foreach ($user in $reportObject) {
  if (([datetime]$user.AccountExpirationDate).AddDays(-14) -eq $TodayOnly) 
  {
    $Name = $user.name
    $to = $user.SACSubmitterEmail
    $subject =  "Your contractors's login account will expire in two weeks!"      
    $hello = $user.SACSubmitter
    $AccountExpirationDate = $user.AccountExpirationDate # -as [datetime]
    $TotalLogonCount = $user.TotalLogonCount
    $LastLogonDate = $user.LastLogonDate
    $body =  "Hello $hello,<br><br>"
    $body +=  "The login account you requested for <b>$Name</b> will expire in one week on <b> $AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "$name logged onto our systems a total of <b>$TotalLogonCount</b> times with the last successful log in posted on <b> $LastLogonDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "<a href='http://intranet/form.cfm?id=100'>If this account needs to remain active please submit a new System Access Control Request by clicking here.</a><br><br>"
    $body +=  "Kind Regards,<br>"
    $body +=  "Your friends in IT<br><br><br>"
    $body +=  "<i>Data generated $RightNow</i>"
    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $mail.IsBodyHTML=$true
    $server = "mail.organization.org"
    $port   = 25
    $Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server,$port
    $Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $smtp.send($mail)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```
if ($user.LastLogonDate){
   #$user.LastLogonDate is not null, use the value
   $obj | add-member noteproperty 'LastLogonDate'($user.LastLogonDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
} else {
    #$user.LastLogonDate is null, use never
   $obj | add-member noteproperty 'LastLogonDate' 'Never'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) remove this first PSobject, it's not needed. replace with step 2

```
  $obj = new-object PSobject
  foreach ($user in $userList) 
  {
```

2.) split off the 0day users from the user list

```
$0dayUsers = $userList  |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -like ''}
```

3.) remove 0day users from the original list

```
$userList = $userList  |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -notlike ''}
```

3.) add this below your 14 day contractor notice at the bottom, I've padded around the one change.  I've left it up to you on how to tailor the sample to your target audience

```
foreach ($user in $0dayUsers) {

  
    $Name = $user.name
    $to = $user.SACSubmitterEmail

    $subject =  "Notice regarding orphaned account!" 
         
    $hello = $user.SACSubmitter
    $AccountExpirationDate = $user.AccountExpirationDate # -as [datetime]
    $TotalLogonCount = $user.TotalLogonCount
    $LastLogonDate = $user.LastLogonDate
    $body =  "Hello $hello,<br><br>"
    $body +=  "The login account you requested for <b>$Name</b> will expire in one week on <b> $AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "$name logged onto our systems a total of <b>$TotalLogonCount</b> times with the last successful log in posted on <b> </b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "<a href='http://intranet/form.cfm?id=100'>If this account needs to remain active please submit a new System Access Control Request by clicking here.</a><br><br>"
    $body +=  "Kind Regards,<br>"
    $body +=  "Your friends in IT<br><br><br>"
    $body +=  "<i>Data generated $RightNow</i>"
    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $mail.IsBodyHTML=$true
    $server = "mail.organization.org"
    $port   = 25
    $Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server,$port
    $Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $smtp.send($mail)
}

### The single curly brace is intentional, the if statement was removed since Select-Object already handled it.
```